# Application of chain rule to prove a derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If I define $x^n= e^{n log x}$ for positive x and $n\in\mathbb{R}$, how do I prove that $\frac{d}{dx} x^n=nx^{n-1}$

Answer (score 2):

If you can use any differentiation technique other than the power rule itself:
\begin{align}
\frac d{dx} e^{n \ln x}&=e^{n \ln x}\frac nx & \text{chain rule} \\
&=x^n\frac nx\\
&=nx^{n-1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You can also use logarithmic differentiation. If $$y=x^n= e^{n \log x}$$ $$\log(y)=n\log(x)$$ $$\frac{y'}y=\frac n x$$ $$y'=\frac n x y=\frac n x x^n=n x^{n-1}$$